# How to create a paging menu with UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to create a paging controller that appears right under the navigation bar. It has to look like a normal cell and also it needs to be scrollable. So according to the centered cell, the content of a tableView below of this paging menu, has to be changed.

[Appearance of how the paging menu cell hast to look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkKuN.png)

So far, I've tried with a collection view embedded in a table view cell, however as I'm doing this, I'm handling the collection view as an extension of the table view cell, thus, I've been unable to reload the table view.

Is there a better approach to achieve this or if this is the way that I should keep following, how can I accomplish my goal?

Comment: I don't recommend nesting collection views in a table view.  Sure, it's possible, but it tends to get messy quick.  A UIPageControl is probably your best bet, it was designed for paging.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but as I understand using a UIPageControl instantiates all pages, which might not be the best scenario if I'm already loading additional info like images, and other stuff.

If i'm incorrect, how can I do this without having a hard-to-load app?